# Set ImageView at the center of the screen

Tags: android

My problem is may be trivial for other people, but for me I can't make it work. I have layout xml as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tracker_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/display"        
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:opacity="translucent" 

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make the `ImageView` is at the center of the whole screen?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLaout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/tracker_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
    android:contentDescription="@string/display"        
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:opacity="translucent" 

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_centerInParent="true" can be replaced by android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" and android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` as the parent and use `layout_centerInParent`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tracker_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/display"        
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:opacity="translucent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure what that `LinearLayout` is for but I have kept it in there. Perhaps you are populating it programmatically and it's pushing your `ImageView` down. `RelativeLayout` ensures it will always be central to the parent, regardless of other view elements.

Comment: LinearLayout  is for ListView. I have tried RelativeLayout before. The problem is ImageView is set at the center of the screen. But ListView does not appear.

Comment: Please condider posting your actual code that is causing the problem. :)